# How can I use Benchmark to evaluate the performance for a program

Tags: java, encryption, aes, benchmarking

I built a program that encrypts some data fields in the database. 
In this program I choose the encryption algorithm(AES,RC4,...)from the combo box and make encryption and decryption.

The program is working well, but I want to make a comparison between these algorithms. How can I make a comparison and evaluation between these algorithms?  The wanted comparison parameters are encryption and decryption time,the retrieving  queries times on the encrypted data , and also which one is more secure? How can I use the benchmark?

Comment: You could use a profiler to see where your program (or test) spends its time.

Comment: I downloaded it and tried , I notice that it deal with a program as total , but I want to deal with the function of encryption and decryption for every algorithm

Answer (score 0):

**Just in my opinion** : You shouldn't use RC4 in any new systems. It's not so broken that you should actively run from it, but if you have an option (like AES), you should use it.

For time compare :

```
public class gettime {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            // Instead of Thread write your codes here
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        long stopTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println(stopTime - startTime + "msec");
    }
}
```

Comment: yes , you are right but I only want to make a comparison , where  there are another new algorithm called REA .

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't have any idea about REA :)

Comment: But I ask about the methods for making comparison between algorithms or benchmark

Comment: OK (For time) you can use "System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis());" when the methods are starting and ending, after that compare between(AES, RC4) two methods you will realize.

Comment: Im already used some thing like this                                                               long startTimeencAES = System.nanoTime()                                                          String afterConcatjobid = useToEncryptAESDEC.AES_DECRYPT(jobidValue,encform.vkey);
            String afterConcatadress = useToEncryptAESDEC.AES_DECRYPT(adressValue,encform.vkey);                
             elapsedTimedecAES = System.nanoTime()-startTimeencAES;                                  System.out.println(+elapsedTimedecAES + " ns.");